# Using xclip as workaround for missing key on keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xclip

My **q** key is gone from my keyboard.  I'm trying to assign ctrl-a  as a way to enter my **q**'s, so from the bash prompt

```
echo "q" |xclip; xclip  -o
```

outputs a **q**..  but saving that to a script then executing it gets me nothing.  (If I can get that to work, I can use the windowmanager to assign ctrl-a to that script.)  Or will you just tell me to edit a dense X config file somewhere?

Comment: you know about `xmodmap`?

Comment: Now I do, thanks to StackExchange suggesting keyworded-answers based on my question title.  Do you have a one-liner for me (to put into .xinitrc I guess)?